# State-of-the-art C++ library for *sparse* matrices over **Z** and **Q**

Tags: library, c++

I wish to ask what libraries for sparse matrices satisfy the following criteria:

(1) Is very efficient (memory and time wise). Uses vectorization (mandatory) and parallelization (not mandatory, but desirable). My matrices can have dimensions 10^7 x 10^7 or more, with a few entries per column on average (i.e. between 10^7 and 10^9 nonzero entries). Matrix entries are *exact*, either *integers or fractions* (I work over rings **Z**, **Z**_(p) and fields **Z**_p, **Q**).

(2) The matrices can be in [CSR or CSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) format and can be converted into [LIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#List_of_lists_(LIL)) format.

(3) The following (basic) methods must be implemented:

- Matrix multiplication: a.b
- Entry-wise multiplication a*b
- Matrix transpose: a^t
- Apply any function (such as mod integers by an integer or take numerators of fractions or invert fractions) on all nonzero matrix values.
- Let I be a subset of row-indices and J a subset of column-indices. Return submatrices a[I,], a[,J], a[I,J]
- Set all entries in I-rows or J-columns to 0, i.e. a[I,]=0 or a[,J]=0.
- For a vector w of the same length as I, multiply the I-rows in a by the numbers from w, i.e. a[I,]=w*a[I,], so we multiply all nonzero entries in the I[0] row by w[0], and so on.
- For a subset of locations IJ={(i0,j0),...}, set the entries at the IJ-locations in a to be 0, i.e. a[IJ]=0.
- Remove zero entries in a. Sort the entries in CSR format. In Python scipy.sparse, we have [these](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros.html) [two](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sort_indices.html) functions for this.

I currently have no need for other linear algebra operations, the focus is on efficiency (RAM shortages are my trouble) and coefficients (rarely can I find rational coefficients).

I've [googled](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/la-sw.html) a bit and found [NewMat](http://www.robertnz.net/nm_intro.htm), [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), [LinBox](https://linalg.org/overview.html), [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/), [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/), [SuiteSparse](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html), [uBLAS](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html), [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), [blaze](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze/src/master/), [CSPARSE](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse.html), [Trilino](https://trilinos.github.io/), ..., but I have never used those libraries. Do they satisfy all the above conditions? Which is the most efficient (benchmark comparisons are welcome)? Are there any better libraries?